# Unable to download reportyng plugin with maven

Tags: testng, maven-3

I am using reporting with maven to generate xslt reports but getting following error while executing

command:

```
"mvn clean test site org.reportyng:reporty-ng:1.2:reportyng"
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.reportyng-ng:1.2' from the repositories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\RajkumarJain\.m2\repository), reporty-ng (https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/raw/master/dist/maven), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository
```

Comment: I checked it on github and it drops me to a 404 page. And I also checked it in the central maven repository but I didn't find it. Maybe it has been removed from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

yes,it has been removed.If you want to try this with Ant,you can check http://blog.varunin.com/2010/05/generating-selenium-reports-using.html