# unable to generate xslt report in maven Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site

Tags: xslt, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-3

I am trying to generate xslt report for my selenium project in maven using "mvn test site" in command promt. I am getting Build failure. Here is command promt message I am getting--

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project Framework_datadriven_maven: failed to get report for org.reportyng:reporty-ng: Plugin org.reportyng:reporty-ng:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.reportyng:reporty-ng:jar:1.2 in https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/raw/master/dist/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of reporty-ng has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

here is my POM file-

```
<reporting>
<plugins>
<!-- TestNG-xslt related configuration. -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.reportyng</groupId>
    <artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- Output directory for the testng xslt report -->
      <outputdir>/target/testng-xslt-report</outputdir>
      <sorttestcaselinks>true</sorttestcaselinks>
      <testdetailsfilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testdetailsfilter>
      <showruntimetotals>true</showruntimetotals>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

reporty-ng https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/raw/master/dist/maven

running the project using mvn test is working fine. Only facing issue using "mvn test site". I am using maven version 3.3.3. Please help

Comment: your link results in 404. from which maven repo are you expecting to download this plugin?

Comment: this is from my POM file
 <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>reporty-ng</id>
      <url>https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/raw/master/dist/maven</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
what else URL I can try for reporty-ng download?

Comment: this link results in 404 as well. test your link with curl before trying to feed it to maven.

Comment: what else URL I can try for reporty-ng download? I can't find any other

Answer (score 0):

github.com/cosminaru is not available to public anymore. you're not the first one: [Unable to download reportyng plugin with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611132/unable-to-download-reportyng-plugin-with-maven). sorry.